# How to get rid of the “Do Not Disturb” Menu Bar icon?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, do-not-disturb

My macOS menu bar contains a dim crescent moon shaped icon.

[image]

When selected, this menu drops down.

[image]

How do I get rid of this visual affordance?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Uncheck the *Show in Menu Bar* option located in <kbd>System Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Dock & Menu Bar</kbd> > <kbd>Do Not Disturb</kbd>
[image: Do Not Disturb panel in System Preferences app]
Note that you can also show the icon only when Do Not Disturb is active by checking the option and select *when active* option.

Comment: Now it's in Control Center though, or alternatively you can press and hold CMD and drag it away with the cursor (see answer by Egor).

Answer (score 17):

@tama's answer is correct, but as a quicker way you can also hold the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key and drag the icon out of the menubar to remove it.

[image: Demonstration]

This trick works with a number of the macOS system icons in the menubar.

Comment: It didn't work for me in this case

Comment: Added demonstration GIF to the answer - it definitely works for me.

Comment: Nice one! I completely forgot about this method. It works with every Control Center widgets.

Comment: Rather annoyingly, you can also click the icon to display the menu then drag the "Do Not Disturb" header to remove/rearrange the icon. I do this accidentally all the time with the sound menu.